# python pip3 can't find threading module

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, installation

I have both python 2.7.6 and 3.4.0 on my ubuntu 14.04. I want to be able to use both as some works were based on the older version. I started using 3 and want to get pip3 for package installation.

When I tried `apt-get` to get pip3, it failed. After a few SO searches, someone suggested installing it with `aptitude` which finally succeeded.

When I run pip3, i got this error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/queue.py", line 4, in <module>
import threading
ImportError: No module named 'threading'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 351, in 
load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2363, 
in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2088, in load
entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.log import logger
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/log.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip import backwardcompat
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-
packages/pip/backwardcompat/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
from queue import Queue, Empty
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/queue.py", line 6, in <module>
import dummy_threading as threading
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/dummy_threading.py", line 45, in <module>
import threading
ImportError: No module named 'threading'
```

Comment: this module doesn't exist

Comment: [`threading` is part of the Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/threading.html). Maybe check your installation or reinstall Python?

Comment: @handle Does it seem my python 3 is broken? I can launch it on command line though.

Comment: What happens if you run it and then type `import threading`+ Return?

Comment: I'm not on Linux - check which Python packages are installed. Look for something like `libpython`.